# I write "composer require larabook/gateway" for install the package but I get this error

Tags: laravel

I am trying to require the `larabook/gateway` composer package by running `composer require larabook/gateway`. I'm using Laravel 5.8, php 7 and version ^3.3 for larabook/gateway. This however yields the following error:

> ./composer.json has been updated
>   Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages
>
> Problem 1
>       - Conclusion: don't install larabook/gateway 3.3.4
>       - Conclusion: don't install larabook/gateway 3.3.3
>       - Conclusion: don't install larabook/gateway 3.3.2
>       - Conclusion: don't install larabook/gateway 3.3.1
>       - Conclusion: remove nesbot/carbon 2.16.3
>       - Installation request for larabook/gateway ^3.3 -> satisfiable by larabook/gateway[3.3, 3.3.1, 3.3.2, 3.3.3, 3.3.4].
>       - Conclusion: don't install nesbot/carbon 2.16.3
>       - larabook/gateway 3.3 requires nesbot/carbon ~1.20 -> satisfiable by nesbot/carbon[1.20.0, 1.21.0, 1.22.0, 1.22.1, 1.23.0,   1.24.0, 1.24.1, 1.24.2, 1.25.0, 1.26.0, 1.26.1, 1.26.2, 1.
>   26.3, 1.26.4, 1.27.0, 1.28.0, 1.29.0, 1.29.1, 1.29.2, 1.30.0, 1.31.0, 1.31.1, 1.32.0, 1.33.0, 1.34.0, 1.34.1, 1.34.2, 1.34.3, 1.34.4, 1.35.0, 1.35.1, 1.36.0, 1.36.1, 1.36.2].
>       - Can only install one of: nesbot/carbon[1.26.3, 2.16.3].
>
> - Installation request for nesbot/carbon (locked at 2.16.3) -> satisfiable by nesbot/carbon[2.16.3].
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

Could you please help me find out what causes this error and how to prevent it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You (probably) have an entry in your composer file for `nesbot/carbon` which resolved to version `2.16.3` while `larabook/gateway` required the same package at version `~1.20`, the version your composer is locked to does not satisfy this requirement. To solve this you will need to either remove your direct version of `nesbot/carbon` (please note that this might break some code of yours) or check with the maintainers of `larabook/gateway` if they can support the `2.16.3` version of the `carbon` package.